# Mono (Linux, C#): DLL in same folder can not be found (System.DllNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, linux, mono, raspberry-pi3, dllimport

I am trying to run an C# program on my Raspberry Pi 3 using mono. The program starts correctly, but as soon as I reach a point where I use some OpenCV libraries the program error with the following output:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: opencv_core220
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Emgu.CV.CvInvoke:cvRedirectError (Emgu.CV.CvInvoke/CvErrorCallback,intptr,intptr)
  at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor () [0x00023] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth].AllocateData (System.Int32 rows, System.Int32 cols, System.Int32 numberOfChannels) [0x0002e] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth].set_Bitmap (System.Drawing.Bitmap value) [0x00050] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth]..ctor (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp) [0x00008] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
  at App.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00122] in <b44d2f4f9f83495091806ba3e6a1570f>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: opencv_core220
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Emgu.CV.CvInvoke:cvRedirectError (Emgu.CV.CvInvoke/CvErrorCallback,intptr,intptr)
  at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor () [0x00023] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth].AllocateData (System.Int32 rows, System.Int32 cols, System.Int32 numberOfChannels) [0x0002e] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth].set_Bitmap (System.Drawing.Bitmap value) [0x00050] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth]..ctor (System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp) [0x00008] in <4f43ef68be294203a100f85f9cebb2b6>:0 
  at App.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00122] in <b44d2f4f9f83495091806ba3e6a1570f>:0
```

The mentioned library "opencv_core220" is a dll located in the same directory as the exe I exececute using mono.
What can I do to fix this problem?
I never worked with mono so far, but I read you can not use dlls on linux, like on windows, but you have to use so-files. But I got no idea how to get them from my dlls. 
The program totally works on windows.

Comment: try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$pwd mono yourProgram.exe`

Comment: or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) mono yourProgram.exe`

Answer (score 0):

There are dlls with .net bytecode and dlls which use windows native code. You need the equivalent files, which use Linux native code!

Answer (score -2):

convert .dll file to .so file and add .so file to /usr/lib. Then run your exe and check

Comment: you can't convert Windows dll-files to so files!